# When a power series in two variables is a finite sum of products of series

Tags: polynomials, power-series, tensor-products

Consider the infinite sum
$
\sum_{k \geq 1} p_k(x,y),
$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_1(x,y) &= 1, \\
p_2(x,y) &= y + xy^2, \\
p_3(x,y) &= y^2 + xy^3 + x^2 y^4, \\
\vdots \\
p_n(x,y) &= y^{n-1} + x y^n + \dots + x^{n-1}y^{2(n-1)}, \\
\vdots
\end{aligned}
$$

How can one show that this sum cannot be written as a finite sum of products of series in one variable, i.e.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \left( \sum_{k \geq 0} a_{i,k} x^k \right) \left( \sum_{l \geq 0} b_{i,l} y^l \right),
$$
where $a_{i,k}, b_{i,l} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $N \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. What tools can be used here?

I think one can reformulate the question in the following way: How can one show that the function $ f(x,y) = \sum_{k \geq 1} p_k(x,y) \in C^{\infty}(I_1 \times I_2) $, but not in $C^{\infty}(I_1) \otimes C^{\infty}(I_2)$ for some open subsets $I_1, I_2 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ containing $0$.

Comment: You can multiply by $1-y$. If there is a solution, then there is also one for $1+xy^2+x^2y^4+\ldots$

Comment: Does $a_k^i$ mean the $i$th power of $a_k$, or is it a two-index set of $a$?

Comment: @Empy2 these are just indices, not powers. I edited the question, thank you.

Comment: Let $A_k=(a_k^1,a_k^2,\ldots,a_k^N)$, then consider dot products of $A_k$ and $B_l$.

Comment: @Empy2 beat me to it, but to put it another way, if it were true that there was such a representation, it would follow that the coefficients of $x^ny^m$ would have to be a sum $a_{1, n}b_{1, m} +  a_{2, n}b_{2, m} + ... + a_{2, n}b_{2, m}$.

Comment: @Empy2 I think I managed to show it using both your ideas: One can look at vectors $A_k = (a_{1k}, ..., a_{Nk})$ and $B_k = (b_{1k}, ..., b_{Nk})$ with relations $\langle A_i, B_{j} \rangle = 1 $ if $ j = 2i $ and $0$ otherwise. These relations correspond to the series $\sum_{k >= 0} x^k y^{2k} $. Will double check and post it if it really works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I note in comments, multiply the expression by $1-y$, and redefine the polynomials in $y$.  We get $$1+xy^2+x^2y^4+x^3y^6+\ldots =\\
\sum_{i=1}^N \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_{ij}x^j\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty b_{il}y^l\right)$$
Define the vectors $A_k=(a_{1k},\ldots,a_{Nk})$ and $B_k=(b_{1k},\ldots,b_{Nk})$.
After multiplying by $1-y$, we have the dot product of $A_k$ with $B_{2k}$ is 1, for any $k\ge0$, and all other dot products are zero.

The set of vectors $\{A_0,\ldots,A_N\}$ is linearly dependent, so there is an expression $\sum c_iA_i=0$, with some $c_k\neq0$.
If you take the dot product with $B_{2k}$, the left-hand side gives $c_k$ but the right-hand side gives zero.  That is a contradiction.

Comment: I did it a bit differently, but got the same contradiction. Thank you